# Listview and mutually-exclusive togglebuttons

Tags: android, android-listview, togglebutton

I have a listview with custom listitems. Each listitem has a togglebutton. This button enables his own time chronometer, in same listitem.

Only one chronometer can be activated at same time. How can I disable the other chronometers when I activate one of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't posted any code, so there are two ways to do this:

- If you did this the easy way, with [ListView#setChoiceMode(`CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE`)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setChoiceMode%28int%29), then this should handle itself.
- If you created a custom adapter to save the toggle state from [view recycling](http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/TurboChargeUiAndroidFast.html) after scrolling. Simply keep a reference to the active row in your adapter. When the toggle changes the uncheck the previous active toggle if it is visible and `getView()` will handle the rest.

If you want specific advice please be more specific about what you have done (showing the relevant code) and why it doesn't work (with the LogCat if there are errors).

Comment: FYI the link to https://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/TurboChargeUiAndroidFast.html is broken now